# How can I use HTML 5?

Tags: html

I want to get ready for HTML 5 and start playing around with it. Do I need to install it or something before using it? How does it work? I'm currently on shared hosting.

Comment: http://diveintohtml5.org

Comment: Dive Into HTML5, along with all of Mark Pilgrim's work, is now gone. A community replacement can be found at http://diveintohtml5.info/ .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HTML5 isn't a server-side technology. All you need to get started is a browser that supports HTML5.

See these pages for HTML5 support in different layout engines:

http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/Implementations_in_Web_browsers
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(HTML5)

Answer (score 6):

You don't "install" HTML5 - did you install XHTML 1.1, or HTML 4.x?  (no is the answer I'm looking for). Certain browsers support HTML 5 and some don't.

HTML 5 Browser Support/Engines: [Comparison of layout engines (HTML5)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(HTML5))

HTML 5 Working Draft:[HTML 5 Working Draft](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to install anything. Just a texteditor and a webserver is enough. You only need to hope that the webpage visitors uses a webbrowser which supports HTML5 fully. Right now, there aren't many of them out.

Comment: To the contrary, all the major modern browsers support key parts of HTML5. And IE can be made to work with some of those same parts with help from javascript.

Comment: You don't need a webserver to play with html5

Comment: @xenoterracide: Lol, you need it to publish it into the world wide web :)

Answer (score 2):

It is the fifth revision of the HTML standard. HTML5 is also a potential candidate for cross-platform mobile applications.On 18 January 2011, the W3C introduced a logo to represent the use of or interest in HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

`<!DOCTYPE html>` is the doctype of HTML 5, add it on the top of your document.

Even if you didn't add the doctype, HTML 5 tags still work (if supported).

Answer (score 0):

No.

Like all HTML it has nothing to do with hosting (unlike PHP etc).

Just create your own page with HTML5 elements and upload it to your hosting. Then you can view the page in you browser, if the browser supports HTML5 of course.